# Probability of Win by Two

Tags: probability, solution-verification

Question: You play a game of chess. There is a 75% probability that you draw. If you
don't draw, there is a 2/3 chance you win and a 1/3 chance you lose. What
is the probability that you win the match if a match is the first person to
win two games?

My solution: First I calculate win or loss probability for each game, $P(Win)=\frac{2}{3}\times\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{6}$, $P(Lose)=\frac{1}{3}\times\frac{1}{4}=\frac{1}{12}$.

Ignoring tied games, there are only 3 permutations of W and L that I can win: WW, WLW, LWW. Then we can add draws in between Ws and Ls, which will not affect the result.

WW: $(\frac{1}{6})^2*((\frac{3}{4})^0+(\frac{3}{4})^1+(\frac{3}{4})^2.....)$

WLW: $(\frac{1}{6})*(\frac{1}{12})*(\frac{1}{6})*((\frac{3}{4})^0+(\frac{3}{4})^1+(\frac{3}{4})^2.....)$

LWW: $(\frac{1}{12})*(\frac{1}{6})*(\frac{1}{6})*((\frac{3}{4})^0+(\frac{3}{4})^1+(\frac{3}{4})^2.....)$

Adding up 3 cases, I have $\frac{7}{54}$.

I would like to have someone confirm if my solution is valid. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can completely ignore any and all ties.  Go ahead and play until a third game didn't result in a tie, even if a winner was already determined.  You are the winner iff you won two games or three games out of the three games which weren't ties.  Using binomial distribution here, that occurs with probability $\dfrac{3\cdot 2^2 + 2^3}{3^3} = \dfrac{20}{27}$

Comment: As for what you accidentally calculated... if we were to rearrange things with the summation out front instead... it looks like you calculated the probability that you win but any and all ties that occurred happened to be before any game happened to have a winner.  We should also have been allowed ties between the wins and losses.  If you were to correct your attempt by adding an exponent of $2$ on your sum for the first case and an exponent of $3$ for the others, you would get the correct value.

Comment: Are you looking for the probability of winning two in a row? Or just winning two? I think you meant win by two, but it isn't clear from your question

Comment: @EkeshKumar given the attempt and the phrasing within the question, it seems clear to me that it is "first to receive two wins in total is declared overall winner" and these don't need to be in a row.

Comment: Oops, you're right. @JMoravitz. Thanks for pointing that out. Not sure how I looked over the second example.

Comment: @EkeshKumar I meant first one to win total of 2 games

Comment: @JMoravitz Thanks for your comments. They are really helpful!